# discord.py - Конфликт трёх функций. Как поправить?

Tags: python, discord.py

У меня в боте конфликтуют две команды и ивент. Все они работают исправно по отдельности, но если не закомментировать ивент (код ниже будет), то команды перестают работать, роль не выдаётся и не забирается, не отправляется сообщение от бота. При этом в консоли не показывается никаких ошибок. Если закомментировать ивент, то команды начинают работать исправно. Как сделать так, чтобы всё это работало вместе?

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Крутая роль")
async def add_crole(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    role = member.guild.get_role(990654610282803311)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'Крутая роль выдана {member.mention}')


@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Крутая роль")
async def rem_crole(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    role = member.guild.get_role(990654610282803311)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'Крутая роль снята у {member.mention}')


#тот самый ивент, при котором если закоментировать его, начинают работать две команды выше
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    guild = client.get_guild(665116256231489548)
    member = message.author
    role = guild.get_role(990654610282803311)
    channel = client.get_channel(990654965649399829)
    if message.channel.id != 990654965649399829:
        return
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if role not in member.roles:
        await message.delete()
        await channel.send(f'{member.mention}, тебе не разрешено писать в этот канал.')
        print(f'{member} попатался сказать "{message.content}", но не имеет прав на разговор в канале крутых.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в `on_message()` строку для проверки наличия команды в сообщении

```py
await client.process_commands(message)
```

Подробнее — [**бот игнорирует команды**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/problems/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B.md)